# Please give a step-by-step explanation of how Infix class from the Python Infix Hack instantination and operators overloading work

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators

[This article](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) shows a way to create custom infix operators using functional programming in python.

Here is a simplified version of Infix class described in the article:

```
class Infix:
def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function
def __ror__(self, other):
    return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
def __or__(self, other):
    return self.function(other)
```

And some examples of its usage:

```
# simple multiplication
x=Infix(lambda x,y: x*y)
print 2 |x| 4
# => 8

# class checking
isa=Infix(lambda x,y: x.__class__==y.__class__)
print [1,2,3] |isa| []
# => True
```

I think I understand the righthand version of the operators and how the double underscore methods work but I just can't wrap my mind around how this hack works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2 |x| 4` calls `x.__ror__(2).__or__(4)`. Now `x.__ror__(2)` returns `Infix(lambda arg, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, arg))`, where in this case `self.function` is `lambda x,y: x*y` and `other` is `2`. So we get: `Infix(lambda arg, self=x, other=2: other * arg)`. On this we call `.__or__(4)`, which returns `self.function(other)` where `other` is `4`. So:

```
(lambda arg, self=x, other=2: other * arg)(4)
   ===
arg = 4
self = x
other = 2
other * arg
   ===
4 * 2
   ===
8
```

So we get 8.